# Permission denied on external write

Tags: android, io, permissions

I am attempting to learn how to read/write to external drive (or even onboard drive) using a picture saved to a file.  This code snippet is directly from android developers API and I am getting the EACCES Permission Denied error.  I do have write permission and using camera hardware in the manifest.  I've read about why this is happening but I haven't seen a solution that would help me specifically.  My device is rooted so I thought I could skirt this problem but apparently not.  Since I am new to this part of Android I may not be recognizing what I should actually do about this problem.  Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

```
//set up an intent to take a picture
private void dispatchTakePictureIntent() {

    log("in dispatchTakePictureIntent()");
    Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    // Ensure that there's a camera activity to handle the intent
    if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        // Create the File where the photo should go
        File photoFile = null;
        try {
            photoFile = createImageFile();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            // Error occurred while creating the File
            log("Exception caught.  Aborting image creation" + ex);
        }
        // Continue only if the File was successfully created
        if (photoFile != null) {
            takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,
                    Uri.fromFile(photoFile));
            startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO);
        }
    }
}

//set up a file for the impending picture
private File createImageFile() throws IOException {

    log("in createImageFile()");
    // Create an image file name
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
    File storageDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
            Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
    File image = File.createTempFile(
        imageFileName,  /* prefix */
        ".jpg",         /* suffix */
        storageDir      /* directory */
    );

    // Save a file: path for use with ACTION_VIEW intents
    mCurrentPhotoPath = "file:" + image.getAbsolutePath();
    return image;
}

    //Snippet of manifest file
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="18"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

<uses-feature 
    android:name="android.hardware.camera"
    android:required="true" />

<uses-permission 
    android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
    android:maxSdkVersion="18" />
```

Comment: Which android version device you are using?

Comment: Try to remove maxsdkversion from write permission.

Comment: removing maxsdkversion worked.  Thanks a bunch man!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up having to remove

```
android:maxSdkVersion="18"
```

from the manifest file.